# The interface is not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good afternoon/evening, I am currently in the process of creating the website and decided to test its adaptability. Everything looks good on the computer:

[image: PC version]
[image: Phone version]

But when I transferred it to the phone (Redmi Note 9 PRO and Samsung Galaxy J1), the following came out:

[image]

For some reason, the phone browser does not see the imported styles and JS. I have a questions: if I put it on hosting, will it be the same stuff? And why doesn't the phone see the styles?

If you need meta tags and file paths, then here they are:

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/icons/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

I hope to get an explanation of why this is happening, thank you in advance

Comment: how you can access your html file in mobile phone?

Comment: _"And why doesn't the phone see the styles?"_ - how could be possibly know, when we get shown nothing but screenshots of what the _result_ looks like? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I moved the entire folder with the project to my phone, that is, all the files were in the right directories

Comment: FYI: Your phone isn't able to open the assets(images, CSS, javascript,...) files if you just transfer them to your phone

Comment: Why? Even if they are in the same folder?

Comment: Because it's sandboxed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're opening your files directly, and that you might need a http server like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

You can get it to listen to 0.0.0.0, and then you should be able to open it through your local IP.

Comment: That is, if I still put it on hosting, everything will be fine?

Comment: Yeah. Your phone isn't able to find your files locally. So you'd have to use something like that, and change all your ./ (dot slash) references to just / (single slash). And then serve them through a server. I use http-server a lot and I think it's nice to just be able to open a folder and go "http-server -a 0.0.0.0" to open test stuff on mobile

Comment: But you can also use parcel for this https://parceljs.org/ since it'll serve your http files